# warning mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo una plataforma escolar, donde necesito conectar mi **base de datos** con mi página web. Sin embargo me aparece esta advertencia al ejecutarlo:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sor Juana\config.php on line 16

Y este es el código PHP:

```
<?php

function conectar () {
    // Create connection
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "bd_preparatoria";
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //if (!$conexion) {
        //echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
    //}
    //else {
        //echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
    //}
    mysqli_select_db($dbname,$conexion);
    return $conexion;
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes cambiados los parametros.Prueba esto 
`mysqli_select_db($conexion,$dbname);`

Comment: @IvanBotero  Lo que dices no es del todo cierto,`mysqli_connect`se utiliza para realizar la CONEXION con la base de datos, mientras que `mysqli_select_db` se encarga de SELECCIONAR la base de datos con la que se van a realiar las consultas.

Answer (score 1):

Había una cierta confusión en el código.

a. Estabas usando dos variables para lo mismo: el nombre de la base de datos ([ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.examples-basic.php)).

b. La forma de establecer el charset no era la correcta ([ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php))

c. Estabas haciendo el return antes de establecer el chartset. En una función lo último es el return, si ésta retorna algo.

```
<?php
function conectar(){
// Create connection
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "bd_preparatoria";
```

<s>`$bd = "el nombre de tu base";`</s> es lo mismo que $dbname

```
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    /* cambiar el conjunto de caracteres a utf8 */
    if (!mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8")) {
        printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
    } else {
        printf("Conjunto de caracteres actual: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conexion));
    }
    //Por último retornas la conexión con el charset utf8 seteado. 
    return $conexion;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema hace un tiempo, y pasa que al usar  `mysqli_select_db` muestra este problema, pero si lo dejas da siguiente manera, te puede funcionar (por lo menos a mí me resultó):

El asunto es no separar la variable `BD`.

```
<?php

function conectar () {
    // Create connection
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "bd_preparatoria";
    $bd = "el nombre de tu base";
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $bd);
    //if (!$conexion) {
        //echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
    //}
    //else {
        //echo 'Conectado a la base de datos';
    //}
    mysqli_select_db($dbname,$conexion); // esto se lo quitas
    return $conexion;
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf");
}

?>
```

Comenta si te resultó útil.